# how to transform sql query to laravel query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-8

I'm a beginner so I'm still struggling with this.

I need your help to convert this query to Laravel's query
but apperently this one doen't work even in PhpMyAdmin.

```
SELECT `candidats.id`
FROM `candidats`,
     `candidatures`
WHERE `candidats.id` = `candidatures.candidat_id`
ORDER By `candidatures.date_depot`;
```

**What I want to do is to display all the candidates ordred by `etat` but this `etat` that belongs to `candidatures` table**

In `Candidat` Model :

```
class Candidat extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'candidats';
protected $fillable = [
    'id_service',
    'demande',
    'nom',
    'prenom',
    'email',
    'adresse',
    'date_naissance',
    ];

public function candidatures()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Candidature::class);
}}
```

In `Candidature` Model :

```
 class Candidature extends Model
  {
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'candidatures';
protected $fillable = [
    'candidat_id',
    'date_depot',
    ];

public function candidat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Candidat::class, 'candidat_id');
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I've tried

```
     $candidat = Candidat::join('candidatures','candidatures.candidat_id', '=', 'candidats.id')
            ->where('date_depot','=', $motcle)
            ->get();
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to get like this

```
$Candidat = Candidat::with(['candidatures' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('date_depot', 'ASC');
}]);
```